# How to get changed class name of User Control from code behind C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, class, reflection

I created my own User Control with property CssClass that is connected with one of the TextBox inside my User Control and has some class as default.

After I build a page with this control, I add another class (with jQuery) to my user control.

What I want to achieve is to get all class names in code behind. Currently, I got only the default class name without an additional one. I do not have this issue with standard Web Control.

If anyone has an idea how to achieve that?

## **EDIT:**

Small clarification what I want to achieve:  I have my `UserControl` with `TextBox` that has `class = "defaultClass"`. I open website where my control was rendered and I see that my `TextBox` has a `class = "defaultClass"`. Then I clicked some button that using JQuery adding another class to my `TextBox` so after that my `TextBox` has 2 `classes = "defaultClass newClass"`. In the end, I click "End Button" where I made a collection of all controls from a page and I check each of them if it contains class `newClass`. Above scenario works perfect with any Web Control but with my UserControl I see only `"defaultClass"`

**Code:**

```
foreach (Control ctrl in all)
{
    // Some code
    UserControl usc = ctrl as UserControl;
    if (usc != null) {
        var classes = usc.GetType().GetProperty("[PROPERTYNAME]").GetValue(usc,null).ToString();
        //HERE I GOT ONLY DEFAULT CLASS NAME WITHOUT ADDITIONAL ONE I ADDED BY JQUERY
    }
}


* "all" is a ControlCollection of page.Controls
```

Comment: You should tell us what `all` is and how you got it.

Comment: Added on the bottom of question. This is a `ControlCollection` of `page.controls`

Comment: There is lack of information. Is your control initialized in Page_Load? Page_PreRender? Also where are you using this code? You can be losing the class value due to that.

Comment: On PreRender, I'm using this code as a part of Button when I want to take information from the website. But if I was losing it, why I still got the default one?

Comment: By losing I mean your control is overwritten with your setting which would be applied on control creating.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused of what you want...

If you want to get the Class name itself, it is

```
usc.GetType().name
```

But in case you want a list of all properties in the UserControl class, you have to ask for the whole list. You currently only ask for one specific property. So try:

```
var classes = usc.GetType().GetProperties();
```

And if you just need the class names, use the PropertyType attribute of the respective property.

**Another source of error could be:** Does your jquery produce **getter and setter** for the attributes? If not, these are **not visible by "Property"** but as "**Field**" - using GetFields() instead.

Here's an example code, of retrieving the properties:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace Reflection_Test
{
    class UserControl
    {
        public int test { get; set; } // if no getter/setter is set, this is considered as field, not property
        public bool falsetrue { get; set; } // if no getter/setter is set, this is considered as field, not property
        public UserControl control { get; set; } // if no getter/setter is set, this is considered as field, not property

        public UserControl()
        {
            test = 23;
            falsetrue = true;
            control = this;
        }

        public List<string> GetAttributes()
        {
            PropertyInfo[] temp = this.GetType().GetProperties();
                //this.GetType().GetProperties();
            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            foreach(PropertyInfo prop in temp)
            {
                result.Add(prop.PropertyType.ToString());
            }

            return result;
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: I added clarification to my question